# Swift import of C static lib into app gets "undefined symbol" for the access functions

Tags: c, swift, xcode

I made a Swift static lib with .C and .h files only and imported its .a and the .h files into my Swift app.

But app build gets undefined symbols for the two access functions.

I did:
Excluded Architectures > Debug > Any iOS Simulator SDK = arm64
...but still get same build error.

U P D A T E . . .
.a of latest build of static lib is missing the undefined symbols.  Prior build (10/10/2022) has the symbols.
Why doesn't static lib project build the symbols?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: seems that there's some symbol duplication which is not allowed in a static lib. If you make it a dynamic lib it should work

Comment: Baronfac:  Don't want to do that.  It's been working as a static lib.  But something has changed and I cannot import the .a into the app anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that lib project was correct and was not building symbols into the .a

I reverted to prior working lib proj and all is well.